# How to avoid memory leaks with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have implemented a basic position transitioning animations using React JS, Material UI and framer-motion. And I have seen weird issues when the component is transitioning for a long time.

I have added cleanup method inside `useEffect` to avoid any possible leaks, but still I see the animations are laggy and the component is getting slow when I add it to actual codebase.

I tried my best following most of the blogs, but still didn't reach to the solution. Need some help here from this group.

This is what I tried:

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/animated-scroll-gkwyn)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of several `useEffects` in the same function, try using only one `useEffect`.

So in the exampe you gave, it would be something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const ref = container.current;
    if (container?.current?.style?.position === 'fixed') {
      setElementOffset(getSize(container.current));
    }
    let maxGrow: boolean;
    let backToNormal: boolean;
    paddingRange.onChange((rangeStatus) => {
      maxGrow = rangeStatus === '5%';
      backToNormal = rangeStatus === '0%';
      setIsComplete(maxGrow);
      setPosition(maxGrow ? 'static' : 'fixed');
      if (backToNormal) {
        setElementOffset(getSize(container.current));
      }
    });
    
    setElementOffset(getSize(ref));
    return () => {
      setIsComplete(maxGrow);
      setPosition(maxGrow ? 'static' : 'fixed');

      setElementOffset(getSize(ref));
    };
  }, [windowSize.width, elementOffset.offsetTop, paddingRange]);
```

Let me know if you have questions. The documentation for useEffect is https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Thank you let me give a try

Comment: The reason I have multiple useEffects is to handle different scenarios at different times. If I have all in one useEffect then everything will be called at all times. Also I believe there is some issue with my react-framer approach.

Comment: A useEffect will be called at the end of the function right. I think alternatively you can add different components for different purposes and combine them in one.

Comment: ok thank you. Is it the right way to have setState in cleanup return function of `useEffect`? So articles says we should not perform setStates during this.

Comment: Updated the example link